# Adding a comment character to the leftmost column of YAML in Vim

Tags: vim, yaml

When editing the following yaml with Vim:

```
countries:
  - country:
      name: France
```

I can comment out line 2 with `:2s/^/#`<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Case 1). The result is as expected:

```
countries:
#  - country:
      name: France
```

However, when I tried to do the same with `2G^hhi#`<kbd>ESC</kbd> (Case 2), the result will be different :

```
countries:
        #- country:
      name: France
```

Extra 8 spaces are now present before `#`.

What causes this behavior, and how do I achieve the same behavior as Case 1, while using keystrokes somewhat more similar to Case 2 ?

Comment: that is caused by the indent expr. You can simply add a `C-D` to your command, to reduce the automatically inserted indent again: `2GgI#<c-d>`

Comment: Thanks, `C-D` worked!  Realised that something like `:set indentexpr=""` would do too.

Answer (score 1):

`^` in normal-mode vim means "the first non-whitespace column of the line"

`0` in normal-mode vim means "the first column of the line"

Thus, `2G0i#` would go to line 2, column zero, in insert mode, and type `#`.

Comment: I'm afraid `2G0i#` was equivalent to `2G^hhi#`, in this specific case. I forgot `0` and this suggestion was also helpful, though.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying that `0` doesn't take you to the beginning of the line?

Comment: `0` does navigate to the beginning of the line. The problem was however about `indentexpr` issue, as explained by Christian, and `2G0i#` will result in the same consequence as Case 2, depending on the configuration. In one of my environments, `:set indentexpr` will show `indentexpr=GetYAMLIndent(v:lnum)`, where the problem occurs, while it isn't reproduced in another environment where `:set indentexpr` shows `indentexpr=`.